# Remove element if the input text value is empty or null

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to remove a value if the input text is empty or null here is what it looks like

[image]

> As you can see, Choice 1, 2,3 has no input values. Therefore that elements or div should be removed.

Here is my modal html code

```
<div class="modal fade-scale" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Create a Multiple Choice Question</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Question</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="question" id="question" class="form-control"  required />
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3" id="divChoice1">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Choice 1</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="choice1" id="choice1" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required />
                    </div>


                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3"  id="divChoice2">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Choice 2</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="choice2" id="choice2" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3"  id="divChoice3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Choice 3</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="choice3" id="choice3" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Answer Choice</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer" id="answer" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required /> 
                    </div>

                    <input type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-block btn-info" value="Submit" />

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
         <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
       </div>
     </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div>
```

Here is my script code
**P.S -** I tried to conditioned it, if the choices have no values then the element should be removed.Result is, the input text is removed but after i close the modal and edit another data, then the input text is shown again. there's a problem with it. kindly adviced and help thanks!

```
//edit
$('#showdata').on('click', '.item-edit', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data');

        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text('Edit Question');
        $('#myForm').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>teachers/updateQuestion');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            method: 'get',
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>teachers/editQuestion',
            data: {id: id},
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                $('input#question').val(data.question);
                $('input#choice1').val(data.choice1);
                $('input#choice2').val(data.choice2);
                $('input#choice3').val(data.choice3);
                $('input#answer').val(data.answer);

                if(data.choice1==null){
                    $("#divChoice1").remove();
                }

                if(data.choice2==null){
                    $("#divChoice2").remove();
                }

                if(data.choice3==null){
                    $("#divChoice3").remove();
                }

            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Could not Edit Data');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: So dont place 3 empty fields in the modal

Comment: RiggsFolly - hello! sorry but this is not a multiple choice module, i forgot to change the card title if you thought it that way, anyways, i cannot do that i need to remove it still if it has no value

Comment: Instead add code to `Add Another Answer` which adds a input field group to the modal.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - that would be a good idea in the future, but currently i have a fixed module for now. It'd be best to stick first to this to learn more.

Comment: `data.choice1==null` etc never equals `null` because they *exist*.

Comment: @GetSet - I replaced it with 0 but gets a result of blank values

Comment: You basically want to remove these elements if their *values* are some sentinel. However your equality is on the element itself.

Comment: @GetSet - hello! what would be the best solution for this?

Comment: From question do you need remove input for every question if there is any null answer or choice value? I guess this is not the case. May be problem is showing modal always show the input whether it has a value or not, right?

Comment: @AtiqulAlam - hello! very good question I ONLY need to remove any null answer or choice value. Your are correct sir

Comment: Can you try to check if(!data.choice1) instead of data.choice1==null

Comment: @AtiqulAlam - hello, the thing is this: your method works. BUT, if I choose a data with one answer or choice and opens modal then it shows 1 choice. AND if ill choose another data that has more than 2  choices then STILL one choice is still shown. nothing changed at all

Comment: I have answered with more details, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in your success function:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('input#question').val(data.question);

    if (data.choice1 != "") {
        $('input#choice1').val(data.choice1);
        $('input#choice1').closest("div.input-group").show();
    } else {
        $('input#choice1').closest("div.input-group").hide();
    }

    if (data.choice2 != "") {
        $('input#choice2').val(data.choice2);
        $('input#choice2').closest("div.input-group").show();
    } else {
        $('input#choice2').closest("div.input-group").hide();
    }

    if (data.choice3 != "") {
        $('input#choice3').val(data.choice3);
        $('input#choice3').closest("div.input-group").show();
    } else {
        $('input#choice3').closest("div.input-group").hide();
    }

    $('input#answer').val(data.answer);
}
```

Comment: OP actually wants the removal based on an AJAX result. If OP wanted the removal immediately, then there would be no point to include the elements on page load.

Comment: @Niels Prins - hello tried it but even the choice1 that has a value is removed.

Comment: @Niels Prins - method 1 works with javascript, but after I close the modal and open it again then the input is shown again.

Comment: @SummerWinter Can you try this as your ajax success function: https://hasteb.in/nihikedu.js

Comment: @Niels Prins - I got to solve the problem. it seems to be when closing the modal. It copies the same inputs on what you opens first. so I need to reload the page every time I need to open another data. is there any solution to this ?

Comment: @SummerWinter I don't quite understand, did you use my code snippet? (https://hasteb.in/nihikedu.js)

Comment: @NielsPrins - the solution is on the content or elements must be refreshed after closing the modal. but i have no idea how can i start with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the options instead of remove and show the div after every click trigger.

```
if(!data.choice1){
    $("#divChoice1").hide();
}
```

And use show at the very first line of the ajax success.

```
$("#divChoice1").show();
```

Comment: I just post for choice1 as example, you need to write these for other choices as wll